# Split a string in java

Tags: java, string, split

I am getting this string from a program

```
[user1, user2]
```

I need it to be splitted as

```
String1 = user1
String2 = user2
```

Comment: That literal String or a String[] array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this to safely remove any brackets or spaces before splitting on commas:

```
String input = "[user1, user2]";
String[] strings = input.replaceAll("\\[|\\]| ", "").split(",");
// strings[0] will have "user1"
// strings[1] will have "user2"
```

Comment: + one for not being dependent on the location of [ and ].

Comment: true, but he is dependent on a 'blank' behind the comma

Comment: @oliholz: good point, updated answer to split on commas after removing spaces as well.

Answer (score 5):

Try,

```
            String source = "[user1, user2]";
            String data = source.substring( 1, source.length()-1 );

            String[] split = data.split( "," );

            for( String string : split ) {
                System.out.println(string.trim());
            }
```

Comment: I wouldn't name a variable 'string'. There's nothing keeping you from doing it but it leads to 'less readable code'.

Comment: sure, that was a eclipse auto generated foreach default name

Answer (score 2):

Try the [String.split()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) methods.

Answer (score 2):

This will do your job and you will receive an array of string.

```
    String str = "[user1, user2]";
    str = str.substring(1, str.length()-1);
    System.out.println(str);
    String[] str1 = str.split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

From where you are getting this string.can you check the return type of the method.

i think the return type will be some array time and you are savings that return value in string . so it is appending [ ]. if it is not the case you case use any of the methods the users suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

From the input you are saying I think you are already getting an array, don't you?

```
String[] users = new String[]{"user1", "user2"};
System.out.println("str="+Arrays.toString(str));//this returns your output
```

Thus having this array you can get them using their index.

```
String user1 = users[0];
String user2 = users[1];
```

If you in fact are working with a String then [proceed as, for example, @WhiteFang34 suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150826/split-a-string-in-java/6150911#6150911) (+1).

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen thanks very nice. Might I ask how do you get an answer's link?

Comment: underneath each answer I see a "link | edit | flag" line.  The link link is a link to the answer.